# size format of mathematics in Jupyter book

Tags: css, jupyter, python-sphinx, mathjax

I'm converting from R bookdown to Jupyter-books and I have a constant struggle to try to replicate the css that I have used into this project. For example, I prefer serif fonts for easy long-form reading of a textbook and I can make that happen with my own css inside of _static and here's what I use (which is identical to my bookdown text):

```css
p { font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;

color: #0;

font-weight: 500;

font-size: 1.4rem;

line-height: 1.8rem;

margin-top: 1.4rem;

margin-bottom: 1.4rem;

padding-right: 0;

vertical-align: baseline;

}
```

But. When I do this, the mathematics that's rendered by MathJax is tiny...appropriate to the default formatting of the stock san-serif git-looking css for body the body font.

--> This is only wrong for display math: `$$....$$` or `$$\begin{align}...\end{align}$$`. In-line mathematics is properly formatted with the body.

How can I adjust this so that the math rendering is the same size as my body-text rendering?

I'm actually not sure that css is the proper way to mess with MathJax...I suspect it has to be done in the original  which I have no idea how to modify it properly in Jupyter-books. The js in the bookdown html is quite extensive.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's been ~6 months since your post, but I encountered something similar today, found your post, and  wanted to share an answer. I'm sure it's not the only answer, or best for that matter, but it *worked*.

Jupyterbook is a distribution of sphinx that uses mathjax javascript engine. You can edit the 'look and feel' of the rendered tex in your `_config.yml` file like follows:

```yaml
sphinx:
  config:
    mathjax_config:
      "HTML-CSS": {
        matchFontHeight: true,
        scale: 80
      }
```

The output seems to be controlled by the ["HTML-CSS"](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/options/output-processors/HTML-CSS.html#configure-html-css) field. Check the link for a complete list of things you can edit.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That indeed works. I set it to scale: 110...

Comment: @ChipBrock: Do [Raymond Brock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9830259/raymond-brock) and [Chip Brock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12008054/chip-brock) refer to the same person? If so, I suggest merging the accounts. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts.

Comment: You're right. A source of confusion for me... I didn't realize that I could merge them and initiated that process. thanks for pointing me to it.

Comment: I tried to merge them, but that didn't work. I only got one email. I then filed an "other" ticket which was the suggestion if I received only one email for the merge. No action and the request for merge expired.

Comment: @RaymondBrock: OK. I don't really know anything about the merging process. In any case, this answer deserves to be accepted and/or upvoted if it solved your problem.